# Grails spring websocket using shiro security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grails-2.0, shiro, spring-websocket

I am new for **spring websocket**. I want to create **chat application** using **Grails Framework**. When I was googling, I reached to **spring websocket plugin**. In my **Grails application** I have implemented **Apache Shiro Security** and I want to use **Apache Shiro Security** for **spring websocket** to **send message to specific user** in chat application. Please any one help me on it.